# Formatting print_r or var_dump results

Tags: php

I would like new lines and indents shown in this output

```
$a = array(1,2,3,4);
print_r($a);
```

So instead of this:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 2 [2] => 3 [3] => 4 )
```

I would get something like this:

```
Array ( 
  [0] => 1 
  [1] => 2 
  [2] => 3 
  [3] => 4
  )
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I suggest using HTML's [`<pre>`](http://www.tizag.com/htmlT/htmlpre.php) tag (preformatting):

```
echo "<pre>";print_r($a);echo"</pre>";
```

EDIT:

To concatenate the output, you must set the second parameter of [`print_r`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php) to `true` to return the value rather than echoing it:

```
echo "<pre>" . print_r($a,true) . "</pre>";
```

> print_r ( mixed $value , bool $return = false ) : string|bool
> If you would like to capture the output of `print_r()`, use the `return` parameter. When this parameter is set to true, `print_r()` will return the information rather than print it.

Answer (score 9):

By using the HTML `<pre>` tag. Also remember to pass `true` as a second argument to `print_r()`

```
echo '<pre>' . htmlentities(print_r($a, true)) . '</pre>';
```

Also as [@cHao](https://stackoverflow.com/users/319403/chao) points out, if you happen any `<pre>` tags within the data, you'll need to pass the result through `htmlentities()` or `htmlspecialchars()`.

Comment: Note that if the result happens to have `</pre>` in it (or apparently any other HTML, for that matter), this goes all to hell.  I'd recommend HTML-encoding the output.

Comment: Just checked to verify: HTML within `<pre>` elements is parsed.  So *any* HTML could cause issues if it's not escaped.

Answer (score 1):

Simply do this (when working with HTML, which I assume):

```
echo "<pre>", print_r($a), "</pre>"
```

That' s it. If you might wonder why I used `,` instead of `.`:

`echo` takes multiple parameters, using commas is faster then string concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

Easy way to do it, Use var_dump

```
echo '<pre>' , var_dump($variable) , '</pre>';
```