# Trying to parse PHP array and getting Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string

Tags: php, arrays, loops, offset

while trying to loop through this array below I'm getting a fatal offset error.

> Fatal error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in

**This is the array I'm trying to parse...**

```
Array ( 
    [data] => Array ( 
        [total] => 29 
        [currentTotal] => 29 
        [dataList] => Array ( 
            [0] => Array ( 
                [Field1] => https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/320AAOSwHYJlgKh3/s-l300.webp 
                [Field2] => PSA 10 Mike Trout 2011 Bowman Draft #101 RC Rookie Card *TOUGH* Angels SP 
                [Time] => Dec 29, 2023 
                [Field3] => $501.69 
                [Field4] => +$5.00 shipping 
                [Field5] => Auction · 59 bids 
            ) 
            [1] => Array ( 
                [Field1] => https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/xVMAAOSwYR5lV3IS/s-l300.webp 
                [Field2] => 2011 Bowman Chrome Draft MIKE TROUT #101 RC Rookie PSA 10 Gem Mint 
                [Time] => Dec 27, 2023 
                [Field3] => $475.00 
                [Field4] => Free Shipping 
                [Field5] => Buy It Now 
            ) 
            [2] => Array ( 
                [Field1] => https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/PxsAAOSw9kpkC6wx/s-l300.webp 
                [Field2] => 2011 Bowman Chrome MIKE TROUT Rookie RC #101 PSA 10 - Los Angeles Angels 
                [Time] => Dec 23, 2023 
                [Field3] => $475.00 
                [Field4] => +$5.00 shipping 
                [Field5] => Buy It Now 
            ) 
            [3] => Array ( 
                [Field1] => https://i.ebayimg.com/images/g/KsMAAOSwTLZlc6E6/s-l300.webp 
                [Field2] => 2011 Bowman Chrome Draft MIKE TROUT #101 RC PSA 10 Gem Mint 
                [Time] => Dec 15, 2023 
                [Field3] => $450.00 
                [Field4] => +$4.00 shipping [Field5] => Buy It Now 
            )
            ...
```

And this is the php code throwing the error:

```
function insertPriceGuide ($oArray){
    $data = $oArray;
    
    $rowCount = 0;
    
    foreach($data as $key => $val)
    {
        echo $rowCount;
        $imgURL = $val['dataList'][$rowCount]['Field1'];
        $kw = $val['dataList'][$rowCount]['Field2'];
        echo $imgURL.'<br/>';
        echo $kw.'<br/>';
        
        $rowCount++;
        echo $rowCount;
        
    }
```

The loop pulls the first data row but throws "Cannot access offset of type string on string" when getting to next data 'datalist' row? Any assistance would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: `var_dump($val['dataList'])` gives an array? I would do `foreach($val['dataList'] as $datalist)`

Comment: What's the point of `$data = $oArray;`? Why not just use `$data` as the parameter name, or `foreach ($oArray ...)`?

Comment: Actually it should be `foreach ($data['data']['dataList'] as $val)`. Then use `$val['Field1']`

Comment: @Barmar Did you manually enter line breaks or is there a way in the editor to do that? (or maybe a fancy IDE?)

Comment: I did it by hand. It would have been nice if you'd posted it nicely formatted in the first place. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16988905/formatting-print-r-or-var-dump-results

Answer (score 0):

This is because you loop on the bad array.
you should before check if the array `$data` include an `dataList` Key in it.
After you will on the `$data['dataList']`

```
if(array_key_exists('dataList', $data)){
    $rowCount = 0;
    foreach($data['dataList'] as $key => $val)
    {
        echo $rowCount;
        $imgURL = $val[$rowCount]['Field1'];
        $kw = $val['dataList'][$rowCount]['Field2'];
        echo $imgURL.'<br/>';
        echo $kw.'<br/>';
        
        $rowCount++;
        echo $rowCount;
        
    }
}
```